# Mixed Effect Multinomial Logistic Regression Model in R- non-bayesian approach?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models, multinomial

I am attempting to run a multinomial logistic regression with at least 1 (but ideally 2) random effects in R and have been very unsuccessful. It seems like there are very few packages that can handle models that are multinomial, *and* have random effects.

I have anonymised my data (in a rush), so lets say I am investigating the distribution of tennis partners for athletes across matches in the 80's. Each row (n=1050) reflects one tennis game, with the names of the target athlete and opponent, athlete ethnicity, ranks and relative ranks in the league, and total wins during that month.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
> head(df,5)
        Date Athlete Opponent      Ethnicity Rank Rel_rank Opp_rank Opp_rel_rank wins opp_wins
1 1987-09-10    Emma     Nora          Asian    2     0.10        8         0.83   12        7
2 1982-09-14  Olivia     Zoey      Caucasian    5     0.50        3         0.30    5        6
3 1988-11-21     Ava     Mila      Caucasian    9     0.93        9         0.93   11        9
4 1988-09-10  Sophia     Mila South American    8     0.83        7         0.83    7       10
5 1989-01-30  Amelia   Gianna      Caucasian    1     0.30        6         0.66   11       12
```

I want to run this model:

Opponent ~ Ethnicity + Rank + Opp_rank + Rel_rank + Opp_rel_rank + wins + opp_wins +(1|Athlete) + (1|Date)

Key dataset traits / obstacles:
1.My categorical response variable is a factor with 14 levels
2.Athletes sometimes play multiple games on the same day, so Athlete is a source of pesudoreplication
3. Date is also a source of pseudoreplication, as matches on the same day all have the same values for rank and wins.
4. Most packages seem to only allow 1 random effect

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Even to tell me what I want to do is impossible!
I am also willing to change my response variable if needed to a numerical one, as long as it is informative about the opponent. For example I could instead use the opponent rank, or age. The use of a categorical response seems to be at the heart of a lot of my issues

I have all tried all relevant modelling packages I can find. The packages **multinom**, **mlogit**, and **mclogit** all can't handle random effects. The packages **glmmTMB** and **glmmADMB** both can't handle multinomial models. Nor can **glmer**, **lme4**, or any other similar well known packages.
*edit; **mclogit** did not work for me as the data reorganisation was too complex for my dataset. In reality there are 100 columns, so expanding it was too taxing for my computer

The only traditional approach that seems to meet my requirements is **npmlt** from the **mixcat** package, but I get the same error each time which seems to relate to my random effect(s). I have tried removing all NA values, only using one random effect, combining the random effects into one, and nothing works. In the below code, "comb" is the column where I combined the random effect during testing. I read that the data needs attaching before running for this package.

```
> all <- na.omit(all)
> all$Athlete <- as.factor(all$Athlete)
> all$Ethnicity <- as.factor(all$Ethnicity)

> attach(all)
The following objects are masked from all (pos = 3):

    Rel_rank, Opp_rank, Date, Wins, Ethnicity, Opponent, Opp_wins, comb, Rel_rank,
    Opp_rel_rank, Athlete

> model.po <- npmlt(formula = Opponent ~ Ethnicity + Rel_rank*Rank + Opp_rel_rank*Opp_rank + Wins + Opp_wins, 
+       formula.npo = ~ 1,       random = ~ 1 | Athlete,    k = 15)
Error in model.matrix.default(random, data = a) : 
  model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()
```

My dreaded other option that does seem to be appropriate is a bayesian approach using **brms**. I ran the model once with default settings, and got a result with too low an effective sample size. Running that model took overnight, and my computer couldn't handle it. I made increases to the treedepth and iterations to increase my ESS, but I haven't had time to run it yet. I am also not super confident in bayesian model checking, and don't believe that I am able to set priors for this specific type of data.

```
model <- brm(Opponent ~ Ethnicity + Opp_rank + Rel_rank 
             + Opp_rel_rank + wins + opp_wins + (1 | Athlete) + (1|Date),
             data = all, family = categorical(), 
             control = list(adapt_delta = 0.9, max_treedepth = 15),
             iter = 4000, chains = 4)
```

The last bayesian option I tried is **MCMCglmm** but this requires complex data reorganisation which I did not have the skill to complete.

Comment: Also check the [Mixed Models Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html) to make sure you haven't missed any non-Bayesian (or more specifically non-MCMC) possibilities ... ?

Comment: FWIW the task view lists  bamlss, R2BayesX, MCMCglmm, mgcv, mclogit ... (if any of these are incorrect please leave an issue at https://github.com/cran-task-views/MixedModels/issues ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for sharing, I hadn't seen this list! It does seem like all options are bayesian, or for continuous response variables. The others seem to be highly specialised for different types of data, and are beyond my skill level to interpret

Comment: Using individual dates as random effects seems somewhat suspect to me as it will treat the dates as categorical with no sense that 1988-09-10 is close to 1988-11-21 but far from 1982-09-14. Maybe it's apporpriate for your real data, but I would consider (a) leaving Date out, (b) treating it continuously (code it as number of days since the first date in your data), or (c) using just the year as a categorical value for fixed or random effects.

Comment: For you `npmlt` approach where you got an error, if you show the model code attempt that caused the error we might be able to help you debug it. But if you just show the error and not the code there's not much we can do.

Comment: `mgcv` is non-Bayesian and allows at least simple random effects, although I'm not sure it will be practical. `bamlss` allows "penalized mode" estimation, so you would technically be going Bayesian but you wouldn't be dealing with MCMC.  `mclogit` is not Bayesian.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your response, in my actual dataset the dates are actually represented by their serial Excel numbers, so it is treated continuously. I added my code and the errors for my `npmlt` approach. I don't understand data attaching, but read it was needed. The code does not work at all without attaching it. I also read I should make a proportional odds and a non-proportional odds model and compare them, I am not sure about this. I get the same error on both though

Comment: *"in my actual dataset the dates are actually represented by their serial Excel numbers, so it is treated continuously"* that's not correct. Random effects [are always treated categorically](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105794/7515).

Comment: And attaching data is a bad idea - I would avoid it always.

Comment: @GregorThomas Sorry I misunderstood the purpose of your question, you are right the dates are not treated continuously in the models, which is how I want it to be. I was talking about how I have been manipulating the date data in excel, for easier formulas. The models do not work at all without attaching it, and I'm not sure how to go about it otherwise

Comment: I meant that treating dates categorically seems bad unless you have a relatively small number of unique dates. For the example context you give and the example data you show, using date as a random effect seems like a bad idea.

Comment: As for your model not working without `attach`, it is unusual that `npmlt()` doesn't take a `data =` argument, but you can use `with()` rather than `attach()` to wrap it - this is safer as there isn't the danger of your attached columns getting out of sync. Also, I see nothing in the `?npmlt` documentation suggesting that it uses the `effect | column` syntax that `lme4` does - I would try `model.po <- with(your_data, nplmt(formula = Opponent ~ Ethnicity + Rel_rank*Rank + Opp_rel_rank*Opp_rank + Wins + Opp_wins, random = ~ Athlete, k = 15))`